# How do I use the withName() method for an Enumeratum IntEnumEntry

Tags: scala, enums

I am currently using [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) 1.5.13 in Scala 2.12.6. I have the following defined:

```
sealed abstract class PartOfSpeech(val value: Int) extends IntEnumEntry
case object PartOfSpeech extends IntEnum[PartOfSpeech] {
  val values = findValues

  case object Noun        extends PartOfSpeech(0)
  case object Adjective   extends PartOfSpeech(1)
  case object Verb        extends PartOfSpeech(2)
  case object Adverb      extends PartOfSpeech(3)
  case object Numeric     extends PartOfSpeech(4)
  case object Exclamation extends PartOfSpeech(5)
  case object Preposition extends PartOfSpeech(6)
  case object Pronoun     extends PartOfSpeech(7)
  case object Conjunction extends PartOfSpeech(8)
  case object Determiner  extends PartOfSpeech(9)
  case object Article     extends PartOfSpeech(10)
}
```

Then, when I attempt to use the `withName()` method like this:

```
val pos = PartOfSpeech.withName("Noun")
```

...I receive a compilation error indicating the method `withName` is not found. So, given I don't see a ScalaDoc for Enumeratum (at least I have not been able to find them), I don't know how to answer this without digging through its source code. Before investing time in that, I thought I might see if someone else has a simple and/or obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for was implemented on version 1.7.0 of Enumeratum.
you have 2 options to work with:

- EnumEntry with "withName" function.
- StringEnumEntry with "withValue" function.

In both ways you can get your needs

// Option 1:

```
sealed trait PartOfSpeech(val value: Int) extends EnumEntry
case object PartOfSpeech extends Enum[PartOfSpeech] {
  val values = findValues

  case object Noun        extends PartOfSpeech(0)
  case object Adjective   extends PartOfSpeech(1)
  case object Verb        extends PartOfSpeech(2)
  case object Adverb      extends PartOfSpeech(3)
 
}

val pos = PartOfSpeech.withName("Noun") // return 0
```

// Option 2:

```
sealed trait PartOfSpeech(val value: String, val index: Int) extends StringEnumEntry
case object PartOfSpeech extends StringEnum[PartOfSpeech] {
  val values = findValues

  case object Noun        extends PartOfSpeech("Noun", 0)
  case object Adjective   extends PartOfSpeech("Adjective", 1)
  case object Verb        extends PartOfSpeech("Verb", 2)
  case object Adverb      extends PartOfSpeech("Adverb", 3) 
}

val pos = PartOfSpeech.withValue("None") // return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the only way to make this work is for me to implement it myself within the `case object`. So, I added this:

```
private val enumEntryByClassSimpleNameLowerCase: Map[String, PartOfSpeech] =
  values.map(enumEntry => (enumEntry.getClass.getSimpleName.takeWhile(_ != '$').toLowerCase, enumEntry)).toMap

def withName(value: String): Option[PartOfSpeech] =
  enumEntryByClassSimpleNameLowerCase.get(value.toLowerCase)
```

It feels like a hack. I sure hope there's something inside of Enumeratum I am just missing. Please let me know if there is a better way to achieve this outcome. I use enums a whole bunch. So, this boilerplate is going to leak all over my codebase.

Comment: This was addressed in version 1.7.0. Please see this answer for a better pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71405597/501113